# setTimeout() not working in return value

Tags: javascript

I have add `setTimeout` but it's not working. I want to show question after 5 sec of the end of the sound.

```
self.getQuestionText = function() {

    startSound('levelq', false);
    setTimeout(function() {
    return self.questions[self.level() - 1].question;}, 5000);

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make Javascript setTimeout returns value in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129057/how-to-make-javascript-settimeout-returns-value-in-a-function)

Comment: Don't pointlessly **SHOUT AT US**. Just ask your question, clearly and with full information.

Comment: What I have done wrong???? I replied that after semicolon, it still not working...

Comment: The problem is that the setTimeout is async. The getQuestionText function end with the setTimeout. 
You need to create a callback that fires after the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` in asynchronous and returns the value in the callback function. Change the structure of your js.

Instead of:

```
self.getQuestionText = function () {

  startSound('levelq', false);
    setTimeout(function () {
      return self.questions[self.level() - 1].question;
    }, 5000);

  }

// The rest of the code
```

Use callback structure:

```
self.getQuestionText = function () {

    startSound('levelq', false);
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.getQuestionText = self.questions[self.level() - 1].question;

        // The rest of the code
    }, 5000);

}
```

Comment: @MuhammadDanish As this answer is the general reason why this code cannot work I will leave it here for other people in the future. Meanwhile, please edit your question and add more code. Add the code where you try to show the question (What is after `self.getQuestionText = ...` line and what you try to do with the variable). Add the related html too. You probably have some more bugs there.

Comment: I have posted complete code. The code is use to Grabs the question text of the current question in a quiz game.

Comment: Working fine if I not add setTimeout(). But I need to add 5 sec of delay after the end of sound.

Comment: It cannot be the complete code but anyway, [look at the console for errors](http://superuser.com/questions/52263/javascript-error-console-in-chrome) if you have any errors please post them